# How I can use a variable as part of a instance name

Tags: jquery, variables, instance

Inside jQuery, I need to call a javascript instance.
This is an instance of splidejs.com inside of bricksbuilder.io.
The aim is to switch to a certain slide, for example:

```
bricksData.splideInstances.alfhxo.go(0);
bricksData.splideInstances.dxtzad.go(0);
```

As you can see, dynamically I need to change the third part of the instance name (which references the respective Splide attribute).

I tried to include the variable in different ways (at the end only guessing).
But -of course- this is not working:

```
var_gamma = dxtzad;

'bricksData.splideInstances.' + var_gamma + '.go(1)';
bricksData.splideInstances.var_gamma.go(0);
bricksData.splideInstances.[var_gamma].go(0);
bricksData.splideInstances.$(var_gamma).go(0);
```

Any idea how I can this achieve?
If more context is needed, please let me know.

Comment: `let var_gamma = 'dxtzad';` plus brackets

Comment: Sorry - yes -  I had them in my script, mistyping...

Comment: So the issue is a typo-type problem. You have an extra dot before the bracket: `bricksData.splideInstances.[var_gamma].go(0);` should be `bricksData.splideInstances[var_gamma].go(0);` - Please delete the question if you still can

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use the [ notation ]:

```js
var gamma = "dxtzad";
bricksData.splideInstances[gamma].go(0);
```

Comment: Ohhhh, sometimes you need only a small hint; thanks ;-)